# Xamarin Media Plugin Auto start or Timer

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In my iOS Xamarin forms project I'm using `Xam.Plugin.Media` from https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin as follows

```
async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
    {
        DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
        SaveToAlbum = true,
    });
}
```

Is it possible to automatically start video recording or set a timer for the recording to start?

Ultimately, I'm trying to build a lightweight remotely controllable camera app. So the device whose camera is controlled needs to be able to automatically trigger/start the camera.

Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a video or take a photo without user interaction with Xamarin Media Plugin.

At the following link you can find all StoreVideoOptions where offered

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/src/Media.Plugin/Shared/MediaStoreOptions.cs