# Xamarin Forms - Take photograph without any user interaction

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement to take a photograph of a user in Xamarin Forms without them having to press the shutter button.  For example, when the app launches it should show a preview and count down from 5 seconds (to give the user chance to get in position) then take a picture automatically.

I have tried the [Xamarin Media Plugin library](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) however [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55825244/xamarin-media-plugin-auto-start-or-timer) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/499) state that this feature is not a supported.

I have seen a number of dead discussions such as [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83369/how-can-i-set-a-timer-to-automatically-take-a-picture-using-the-mediaplugin) with people asking similar questions without resoltion.

I tried the [LeadTools AutoCapture](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t12741-) sample but this only seems to work for documents/text and not people (unless I am missing something??).

I am now working my way through the [Camera2Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/android50-camera2basic/) sample which is quite old and only targets Android via [android.hardware.camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary).

Are there any samples out there (or 3rd party libraries) that can acheive this requirement?  Ideally I would like it to be cross platform (iOS and Android) but currently the main focus is Android.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect#TaskTakePicture

Comment: Thanks but as far as I can tell that documentation is out of date, the Camera class was deprecated in API level 21. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera. Navigating to the description of the takePicture method seems to confirm this. Also I am looking for a solution in Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the **[Custom View Renderer on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view#creating-the-custom-renderer-on-android)** to achieve that.

**And** based on **[this offical sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-view/)** is more convenient, just modify code as follow can achieve your wants.

This official sample can preview camera view in Xamarin Forms App, we just need to add a `Timer` to call the Frame from Camera after 5 seconds.The modified Renderer code as follow:

```
public class CameraPreviewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomRenderer.CameraPreview, CustomRenderer.Droid.CameraPreview>, Camera.IPreviewCallback
{
    CameraPreview cameraPreview;
    byte[] tmpData;
    public CameraPreviewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomRenderer.CameraPreview> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe
            cameraPreview.Click -= OnCameraPreviewClicked;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(Context);
                SetNativeControl(cameraPreview);
            }
            Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.Camera);

            // Subscribe
            cameraPreview.Click += OnCameraPreviewClicked;

           
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
    {
        base.OnAttachedToWindow();

        // call the timer method to get the current frame.
        Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), () =>
        {
            // do something every 5 seconds
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("get data"+tmpData);
                // using MessagingCenter to pass data to forms
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, byte[]>(this, "CameraData", tmpData);

                cameraPreview.Preview.StopPreview();
                cameraPreview.IsPreviewing = false;
                // interact with UI elements
            });

            return false; // runs again, or false to stop
        });
    }

    void OnCameraPreviewClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cameraPreview.IsPreviewing)
        {
            cameraPreview.Preview.StopPreview();
            cameraPreview.IsPreviewing = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cameraPreview.Preview.SetPreviewCallback(this);
            cameraPreview.Preview.StartPreview();
            cameraPreview.IsPreviewing = true;
            
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Control.Preview.Release();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    // get frame all the time
    public void OnPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
        tmpData = data;
    }
}
```

Now, Xamarin Forms can receive the data from [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center):

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, byte[]>(this, "CameraData", async (sender, arg) =>
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(arg);
    if (stream != null)
    {
        //image is defined in Xaml
        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
    }
});
```

`image` is defined in **XAML**: `<Image x:Name="image" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200"/>`

Comment: Your mentioned example uses `Camera2`, at least now, and your code uses `Camera`, which is deprecated. I guess this can't work? How can I get preview data from `Camera2`?